# iOS Developer Enterprise Program membership Renewal Before Expiration

Tags: ios, membership, ad-hoc-distribution, renewal

I Received an email from the apple for renewal of Enterprise Membership Program, and below are my questions regarding that.

- Is there any effect on the distribution certificates in case of renewal of program before expiration?
- Will the application signed with the distribution certificates continue to run without any problem in case of renewal of program before expiration?
- Will there is need to distribute the enterprise applications again, after renewal before expiration?

Thanks for your answer in advance!

Answer (score 3):

No. Yes. No.

Renewing before expiration causes no affects on existing provisioning profiles. Renewing early will extend your membership one year after the current expiration date. You don't lose any calendar time on your membership by renewing early. Failing to renew on time will invalidate your distribution certificate, causing your enterprise distribution app to fail to install after the expiration date.

So renew before it expires.

Comment: And you can remove unused devices from the portal only after the previous membership expires.

Comment: Lefteris, I understand the instructions to mean that I should remove unused devices from the portal before the renewal. The slots used by those devices are not released for my use until the renewal date. I haven't risked testing if devices slots are freed if I delete a device added before a renewal and removed after a renewal.

Comment: @Lefteris - Thanks for your response, it helps me a lot.